# Search a text in files that have a particular folder in path, then display the matching line and file permissions

Tags: bash, grep, find

Find all the *.config files, that have a particular folder (e.g config) in path and that have a specific text (e.g hostname). Then display the matching lines along with the file permissions.

Right now the below command gives me all the config file that have 'config' folder in path and have 'hostname' text along with the file permission.

```
ls -la `find / -type f -name "*.config" -exec grep -li 'hostname' {} + | grep config`
```

sample output

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 user users  2240 Jan 17  2014 /home/config/1.config
-rw-r--r-- 1 user users  2146 Aug  2  2013 /home/test/config/abc.config
```

These file have text 'hostname' in them. Now I also want to see the line where is 'hostname' match has happened. Is there a way to do it, with out bash scripting ?

Comment: do you need  "file permissions" to be displayed in the output?

Answer (score 3):

Use `find` command options:

```
find -type f -path "*/config/*.config" -exec grep 'hostname' {} \;  -ls
```

---

- `-path <pattern>` - File name matches shell pattern `<pattern>`
- `-ls` - list  current file in `ls -dils` format on standard output

Comment: why does the \ before ; means ?

Comment: I don't think the OP wants the `-ls`. You may want to use `-exec grep -hi 'hostname' {} +` for (slightly) improved efficiency.

Comment: @NikhilGeorge, `\;` - *Both of these constructions might need to be escaped (with a `\'`) or quoted to protect them from  expan‐
              sion  by the shell.* See more extended description in `man find`

Comment: @roaima, that was the way I have interpreted the question, I have left a comment